# Base class throws exception. How to propagate?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

```
class base {
  public:
    base() : value(int()) {
      throw true;
    }
  private:
    int value;
};

class derived : public base {
  public:
    derived() : base() {  // base class constructor called, `value` to be initialized
      // I want this to propagate (rethrow) base class exception... how do I do it?
    }
};

int main(){
  try {
    derived a;
  }
  catch(bool){
    // Base class exception to be caught
  }

}
```

All has been said in the example above. How do I propagate (rethrow) base class exception?

I try this abomination:

```
class base {
  public:
    base() : value(int()) {
      throw true;
    }
  private:
    int value;
};

class derived : public base {
  public:
    derived() : try { base() } catch(bool) {throw;} {
      // ...
    }
};

int main(){
  try {
    derived a;
  }
  catch(bool){
    // Base class exception to be caught
  }

}
```

Does not compile, giving syntax error. Very much expected. What is the solution?

Do not read further. More characters required. Typing more characters.

Comment: Alright, ya sayin' me have to `catch`. How 'bout me catchin' them exceptions this way: `derived() : try { base() } catch(bool){throw;} {}`. Me think it is well smart idea, tho' me homies callin' me an idiot

Comment: You's a well smart man. Me tried to `try` and `catch` as it's written in a comment above. Tho' me homies callin' me bit thick. What's the problem with me code?

Comment: Does not compile, mate

Comment: @user3600124 So post the exact errors you get while compiling. And btw don't forget the `;` at the end of class definitions.

Comment: Alright, me error is very much descriptive `error C2059: syntax error: 'try'`

Comment: @user3600124 The corrected code (with the `;` added) compiles fine for me, and the exception is caught in the `catch` block as expected. If it doesn't work for you, you'll need to 1) make sure you copy/pasted the real code, and 2) fill-in some details about the compiler, version and command line.

Comment: Can somebody answer this question? Not in comments as I am not sure what is the correct answer we are talking about

Comment: Use this:  `derived() try : base() { } catch(bool) { throw; }` ... the syntax in the comment was arranged the wrong way.

Comment: Seems to work. Syntax ugly as hell though. Any external resources (links) on the topic would be much appreciated

Comment: @user3600124 See for example [Function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block). With the additional note that inside the `catch` block around the constructor you shouldn't reference anything in either `base` or `derived` since neither object is properly constructed at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have in your question *already* does exactly what you want ([see demo here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5c731108028eb36)). Exceptions rewind the call stack to the nearest catch block that handles the exception type.

Since the `derived::derived()` constructor does not catch the exception, it automatically propagates to the caller.